# What does "icalendar.publish" method do?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, icalendar

In the icalendar gem's readme they have this example code:

```
cal = Icalendar::Calendar.new
cal.event do |e|
  e.dtstart     = Icalendar::Values::Date.new('20050428')
  e.dtend       = Icalendar::Values::Date.new('20050429')
  e.summary     = "Meeting with the man."
  e.description = "Have a long lunch meeting and decide nothing..."
  e.ip_class    = "PRIVATE"
end

cal.publish
```

What does the `cal.publish` method do? There is no documentation for it, and the source code only shows this:

```
def publish
  self.ip_method = 'PUBLISH'
end
```

That doesn't help—what does `ip_method` do??

If anyone could explain this, it would be a great help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an `optional_single_property` method/hook, see [Github code](https://github.com/icalendar/icalendar/blob/97ed9d301448350de15da4ba3b2323bd685d358c/lib/icalendar/has_properties.rb#L116). This method sets the publish method (refers to iTip).

From [maptiming.com](http://www.maptiming.com/concept/getting-started-with-icalendar-hosting):

> The ‘methods’ are not explained in the iCalendar standard, but in the iTIP standard, and reading of this second standard clarified a lot. These are the supported methods as listed on page 8 of the standard:
>
> PUBLISH: Used to publish an iCalendar object to one or more “Calendar Users”. There is no interactivity between the publisher and any other “Calendar User”. An example might include a baseball team publishing its schedule to the public.

[RFC 5546](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5546) explains the iTip standard.

Another resource mentioned:

> iCalendar used the method PUBLISH instead of REQUEST. Using REQUEST, it just brings up the calendar, while using PUBLISH imported it."